# Protohackers 1: Prime Time Rust, serde_json::fromreader validating readbytes

Tags: multithreading, rust, webserver

Heyo!
I'm learning Rust and trying to solve the protohackers challenge (https://protohackers.com/problems) namely prime time.
I get the following failure when running the test:

```
[Mon Nov 28 14:21:10 2022 UTC] [0simple.test] NOTE:check starts
[Mon Nov 28 14:21:10 2022 UTC] [0simple.test] NOTE:connected to 213.89.253.71 port 5006
[Mon Nov 28 14:21:13 2022 UTC] [0simple.test] NOTE:handled all 25 requests correctly
[Mon Nov 28 14:21:13 2022 UTC] [0simple.test] PASS
[Mon Nov 28 14:21:14 2022 UTC] [1multiclient.test] NOTE:check starts
[Mon Nov 28 14:21:15 2022 UTC] [1multiclient.test] NOTE:connected to 213.89.253.71 port 5006
[Mon Nov 28 14:21:15 2022 UTC] [1multiclient.test] NOTE:connected to 213.89.253.71 port 5006
[Mon Nov 28 14:21:15 2022 UTC] [1multiclient.test] NOTE:connected to 213.89.253.71 port 5006
[Mon Nov 28 14:21:15 2022 UTC] [1multiclient.test] NOTE:connected to 213.89.253.71 port 5006
[Mon Nov 28 14:21:15 2022 UTC] [1multiclient.test] NOTE:connected to 213.89.253.71 port 5006
[Mon Nov 28 14:22:14 2022 UTC] [1multiclient.test] FAIL:alarm timeout after 60 seconds
```

Here is the Code:

```
use std::{net::TcpListener,io::{Result, Read}, thread};
use serde_json::json;
use serde:: {Deserialize};
use std::io::Write;



#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Message {
    method: String,
    number: i64
}

impl Message {
    fn is_ok(&self) -> bool {
        if self.method == "isPrime"{
            return true;
        }
        return false; 
    }

    fn is_prime(&self) -> bool {
        if self.number <= 1{
            return false; 
        }
        for i in  2..self.number {
            if self.number % i ==0 {
                let res = self.number % i; 
                println!("{res}"); 
                return false; 
            }
        }
        return true; 
    }

    fn get_variables(&self){
        println!("Method is: {0}, Number is: {1} ", self.method, self.number);
    }
    
}

fn main() -> Result<()>{

    let addr= "192.168.0.9:5006"; 
    let listener= TcpListener::bind(addr)?; 
    for stream in listener.incoming(){
        let _ :thread::JoinHandle<Result<()>> = thread::spawn(move || {
            loop {
                let mut m = serde_json::Deserializer::from_reader(stream.as_ref().unwrap());
                let msg = Message::deserialize(&mut m);

                match msg{
                    Ok(msg)=>{
                        if msg.is_ok(){

                            let ret_msg = json!({"method":"isPrime","prime":msg.is_prime()});
                            serde_json::to_writer(stream.as_ref().unwrap(), &ret_msg).unwrap();
                            stream.as_ref().expect("Error").write(b"\n").unwrap(); 
                        }

                     }, 
                    _ => {
                        break Ok(()); 
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

I'm not sure if it has to do with me not handling zero bytes received although I think my "match msg" should solve that? Or if it has to do with stream not being mutable or something, I'm really new to Rust and any help is appreciated!

Google google, rust docs, cant seem to find anything. I think it has to do with my lack of understading of rust

Comment: What is happening? What do you want to achieve? What do you expect? How can we reproduce it? Not everyone knows the protohackers challenge. Do us the favor of making it easy for us to help.

Comment: @RIJIK how stupid of me, added link to coding challenge! Basically what I’m trying to achieve is a webserver able to maintain multiple connections handling requests according to a specific format. 
So my webserver recieves something like:
  {”method”:”isPrime”, ”number”:126}\n and I should respond similarly with info if the number is a prime or not by bool!

Comment: Well it seems like your program is stuck somewhere. My guess would be somewhere in the loop. Possibly in the second iteration when the stream is blocking because it is waiting for new data. I suggest figuring out where exactly it gets stuck first. Use println!() in-between the statements and see where it gets stuck.